# What is best practice with regards to communicating between a user control and parent page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I've been tasked with refactoring a mess of a page, and I would like to refactor it in the best way possible. The layout page is 600+ lines, and the code file is nearly 1400. I would like to separate different modules of the page into user controls, but those modules are receiving information, unsurprisingly, from the page they're on. For a short sample:

```
private void btnGetItem_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   product = Products.getAllItemInformation(txtItemNbr.Text);
   txtDescription.Text = product.getDesc();
   setListBoxSelected(listMarketingSegment, product.getMarketingSegment());
}

private void setListBoxSelected(ListBox box, string pipeDelimitedStr)
{
    pipeDelimitedStr = pipeDelimitedStr.Replace((char)253, '|');
    pipeDelimitedStr = pipeDelimitedStr.Trim('|');
    pipeDelimitedStr = "|" + pipeDelimitedStr + "|";
    foreach (ListItem item in box.Items)
    {
        if (pipeDelimitedStr.IndexOf("|" + item.Value + "|") >= 0 && item.Value.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I allow this functionality? A user control needs to be able to access that same product from the parent page, but I'm not sure what the best practice is for that to happen.

I read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication, but I'm not sure how to relate it to my situation. Do I create an interface? Create event driven communication? If so, how do I pass the product information to that user control?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it MVVM way. Create a ViewModel, inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged, define properties for you data. Set datacontext of your parent page and usercontrol as your ViewModel and keep on updating properties. Now on usercontrol and on parent page you can access data using these properties. Here is one  [example](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/07/08/universal-apps-user-controls-and-mvvm/). you will find many more links/example over the net to implement things MVVM way.